# How to configure, Event trigger

Tags: eventtrigger, azure-data-factory

I want to configure event based trigger on blob creation. But i have files only in container with container/files format(no folder inside container). In this case how to configure the trigger? What should be given under 'Blob path begins with'??

Answer (score 0):

The Blob path begins with and Blob path ends with properties allow you to specify the containers, folders, and blob names for which you want to receive events. Your storage event trigger requires at least one of these properties to be defined. You can use variety of patterns for both Blob path begins with and Blob path ends with properties, as shown in the examples later in this article.

- Blob path begins with: **The blob path must start with a folder path.**
  Valid values include 2018/ and 2018/april/shoes.csv. This field can't
  be selected if a container isn't selected.

If your files only in container with container/files format, I'm afraid we can't do that.

For more details, please ref: [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)

But If you think about logic app, it has the trigger [When a blob is added or modified (properties only)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/#when-a-blob-is-added-or-modified-(properties-only)):

- **This operation triggers a flow when one or more blobs are added or
  modified in a container.** This trigger will only fetch the file
  metadata. To get the file content, you can use the "Get file content"
  operation. The trigger does not fire if a file is added/updated in a
  subfolder. If it is required to trigger on subfolders, multiple
  triggers should be created.

You use this logic trigger + [Create a pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#create-a-pipeline-run) or [Get a pipeline run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azuredatafactory/#get-a-pipeline-run) action to achieve your request.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I achieved my requirement.. With ur help

Comment: @Sree you're welcome! If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.